# AWS EMR step in RUNNING state even when job has been completed

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I am running a spark job which partitions data on two columns as an EMR step. The spark job has `spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode` set to `dynamic` and `SaveMode` as `overwrite`.

I can see the Spark job has finished execution by looking at the Spark UI but the EMR step continues to be in RUNNING state for more than an hour. I can also see _SUCCESS file in the root directory with timestamp in line with the spark job completion.

Any idea why the EMR step isn't completing or best practices to speed up the process?